# Padding a Matrix

Tags: matrix

I have the following matrix `test={{x1,y1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3},{x4,y4,z4,u4}}`, I am looking for a rule that 1) finds the max length of a row (=4 in this example) and 2) makes all rows of the same length by adding `0` where there is nothing (`PadRight`?). 
In the example of `test`, my desired outcome is `{{x1,y1,0,0},{x2,y2,z2,0},{x3,y3,0,0},{x4,y4,z4,u4}}`

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `PadRight[test]`?

Comment: oh yes! indeed.

Comment: Luigi, I voted to close because it seems as if `PadRight` does what you need

Answer (score 3):

```
PadRight[test]
```

> {{x1, y1, 0, 0}, {x2, y2, z2, 0}, {x3, y3, 0, 0}, {x4, y4, z4, u4}}